# CreateFile in read mode needs elevated privileges

Tags: privileges, createfile

I am using the same code which I believe has been used before but now in windows 10 it is asking for elevated privileges The code is:

HANDLE fh;
fh=CreateFile("e:\temp\event.dat",
    GENERIC_READ,
    FILE_SHARE_READ,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    NULL);

e: is a physical drive. Any idea why this is complaining?

Comment: Works fine for me using my D: drive (which is a second SSD drive) without elevation.

Comment: It seems that this was not caused by the CreateFile. Taking everything out of the program but a #include <stdio.h> and a printf, it still requests higher privileges. This is a default win32 console command line program.

Comment: Well, as the CreateFile works for me, I clearly can't reproduce what you're describing. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am now to a very minimal comparison. I created two projects one called rawfile and the other called test1. Both had nothing but a printf. The one called rawfile requested higher privileges and the one called test1 did not. Apparently just the project name is the issue. Big brother is watching.

Finally, after a re-boot and creating the project again, the issue seems to have gone away. At one time there was a project on the system also called rawfile which did require higher privileges. It accessed a device directly. Apparently, there was some "memory" of this which took some cleaning to get rid of.